# NullPointerException with JSP/Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have my doGet as:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException{


    String resourceIDstr = request.getParameter("ResourceID");
    int resourceID = Integer.valueOf(resourceIDstr);

    Resource resourceToLend  =  ResourceModule.getInstance()
                                .getResourceByID(Integer.valueOf(resourceID));



    request.setAttribute("resourceToLent", resourceToLend);

    request.setAttribute("innerTab", "LendResource.jsp");
    getServletConfig().getServletContext()
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/resourcelend.jsp")
                    .forward(request, response);
}
```

Whenever I forward any GET request to this servlet, it does not forward request to JSP and instead throws exception as:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The strange thing is this particular JSP is being used by other servlet without any problem and this particular servlet throws exception. I am trying to find the possible causes for the exception.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
servlet.TempResourceLendServlet.doGet(TempResourceLendServlet.java:37)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.admin.resourcelend_jsp._jspService(resourcelend_jsp.java:114)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
servlet.TempResourceLendServlet.doGet(TempResourceLendServlet.java:37)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.admin.LendResource_jsp._jspService(LendResource_jsp.java:84)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.admin.resourcelend_jsp._jspService(resourcelend_jsp.java:114)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
servlet.TempResourceLendServlet.doGet(TempResourceLendServlet.java:37)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: It's an exception in the JSP, so add the JSP contents. And a stacktrace.

Comment: Have you initialized your bean?

Comment: btw To get RequestDispatcher you could use ServletRequest method: `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/resourcelend.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: I have also tried request.getRequestDispatcher() with no success.

Answer (score 3):

As asgoth says, you should provide your jsp in the question, rather than the servlet.

Also, your root cause stacktrace contains a line saying

```
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.admin.resourcelend_jsp._jspService(resourcelend_jsp.java:114)
```

This refers to the automatially created servlet that your jsp has turned into. You will find this in tomcat's work folder - as it's autogenerate java code, you'll have to do some mapping work, but it should be more or less self-explaining what line 114 refers to in your jsp. With this you can find out the root cause for yourself. (last time I've seen those files, they had some comments that referred to the equivalent jsp code)